# Calcular média e desvio dados serie temporal

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Tenho uma base de dados de informacao de consumo de animais. A data de inicio de coleta de consumo de cada animal é diferente.
Segue um exemplo com somente dois animais:

```html
Animal Dia Consumo
5 2 1379
5 3 2264
5 4 2234
5 5 2204
5 6 2369
6 3 1379
6 4 2264
6 5 2234
6 6 2204
6 7 2369
```

Preciso calcular duas coisas:
1) Calcular a média e desvios padrao de consumo de todos os animais com base somente na primeira informacao coletada de animal.

2) Calcular a média e desvio de consumo de cada animal com base nas três primeiras informacoes coletadas de cada animal. Nesse caso preciso gerar uma nova tabela (dataframe) similar a que segue abaixo:

```html
Animal Média Desvio
5 x1 y1
6 x2 y2
```

Se alguem puder me ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isso que você precisa:

```
library(dplyr)
DfConsumo %>% 
  group_by(Animal) %>% 
  summarise(Consumo = first(Consumo)) %>% 
  summarise(Média = mean(Consumo), Desvio = sd(Consumo))

DfConsumo %>% 
  group_by(Animal) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= 3) %>%
  summarise(Média = mean(Consumo), Desvio = sd(Consumo))
```

Na 1ª parte do código, pelo que eu entendi do seu problema, eu pego a 1ª informação de cada animal, e calculo a média e o desvio dessas informações. Na segunda parte, eu seleciono as três primeiras informações de cada animal e calculo as médias e desvios por animal

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu precisava